# How use input type=file to upload json file

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to send a JSON file on a php script called process.php, save the file on a folder and then send this file to a python script.
At the moment the html code is this:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>
```

And the javascript code is this:

```
 const url = 'process.php';
 const form = document.querySelector('form');

 form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
      const formData = new FormData();

      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          let file = files[i];
          formData.append('files[]', file);
       }

      fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData
      }).then(response => {
           console.log(response);
     });
 });
```

Lastly my PHP is this:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $errors = [];
    $path = 'uploads/';
    $extensions = ['json'];

    $all_files = count($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $all_files; $i++) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
        $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['files']['name'][$i])));

        $file = $path . $file_name;

        if (!in_array($file_ext, $extensions)) {
            $errors[] = 'Extension not allowed: ' . $file_name . ' ' . $file_type;
        }

        if ($file_size > 2097152) {
            $errors[] = 'File size exceeds limit: ' . $file_name . ' ' . $file_type;
        }

        if (empty($errors)) {
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file);
        }

    }

    if ($errors) print_r($errors);
}
```

}

In the PHP if I try to print $file_name, the name of the file is printed correctly, but if I try to print the other information the result is an empty string or, in the case of $file_size is 0. 
So, what's wrong ? Must I set something in the apache configuration to upload a file on my web server or I have committed some mistake in my code ?

Comment: Try $_FILES['upload_cont_file']['name'], not $_FILE[...

Comment: @alexkad nothing to do. I receive always the error string

Comment: What *exactly* is the value of `$_FILE['upload_cont_file']['name']`?  (and also `$_FILES['upload_cont_file']['name']`)

Comment: @freedomn-m For both $_FILE['upload_cont_file']['name'] and $_FILES['upload_cont_file']['name']) I don't get anything back or I get an empty string

Comment: Likely offtopic, but certainly shows the code here doesn't match your code: `extension = $('#file-upload').val()`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php *"DO NOT USE $_FILES['upfile']['name']"*

Comment: Looks like an issue in the php - you should remove all the jquery to confirm this - have a simple `<form><input type='file' name='upload_cont_file' /></form>` and get *that* working before you do any (pointless IMO) checks against extensions.  Then test your final solution by taking a picture and renaming it "pic.jpg" to "pic.json" and upload that...

Comment: @freedomn-m I have modified the code, but i'm unable to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the temporary name of the file, the function  is_uploaded_file()  does not accept the file name sent on the client machine, try this:

```
 if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES['upload_cont_file']['tmp_name'] ))
    echo 'file uploaded ';
 else
 echo 'error';
```

Comment: I have already tried also in this way but nothing. I receive always 'error'

Answer (score 1):

If want to upload  and move to specific directory for example images folder

```
if (move_uploaded_file ( $_FILE['upload_cont_file']['tmp_name'] ,'images/'.$_FILE['upload_cont_file']['name']))
{
    echo 'file uploaded ';

}
else
{
  echo 'couldnt file uploaded';

}
```

If you just check file  uploaded to temp folder

```
 if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES['upload_cont_file']['tmp_name'] ))
{
    echo 'file uploaded ';

}
else
{

 echo 'file couldn't upload';

}
```